# Replace python dataframe values and store in another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to replace ['Time Period'] value if it contains Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 & update it in another column ['Date'] as per condition.
But, after execution of below script, last script result will update in ['Date'] column.

dt:

```
Time Period Frequency   Date
2005Q1      2   
2005Q2      2   
2002Q3      2   
2005Q4      2   
2005Q1      2   
2003Q2      2   
2004Q3      2   
2001Q4      2
```

Please help on this.

```
dt['Date'] =  dt[dt['Frequency'] == '2']['Time Period'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('Q1','-01-01'))
dt['Date'] =  dt[dt['Frequency'] == '2']['Time Period'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('Q2','-04-01'))
dt['Date'] =  dt[dt['Frequency'] == '2']['Time Period'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('Q3','-07-01'))
dt['Date'] =  dt[dt['Frequency'] == '2']['Time Period'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('Q4','-10-01'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would work:

```
dt['Date'] = dt[dt['Frequency'] == '2']['Time Period'].apply(
    lambda x: x.replace('Q1','-01-01').replace('Q2','-04-01').replace('Q3','-07-01').replace('Q4','-10-01')
)
```

Comment: Its updating 'Time Period' values, not replacing anything

Comment: can you share a small set of code with some default values, so that I can work with that.

Comment: u can use dataframe mentioned in query, please check above

Comment: I have modified the answer. Let me know if any issues.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = df.loc[df['Frequency']==2, 'Time Period'].replace({
        'Q1': '-01-01',
        'Q2': '-04-01',
        'Q3': '-07-01',
        'Q4': '-10-01'
    })
```

this code work as per your requirement.

Comment: Its updating 'Time Period' values, not replacing anything

Comment: but you want update 'Time Period' in new field "Date"

Comment: so it work as you want.. can you please show me your output generated by my above code.